# LINQ foreign key breaks query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

The LINQ query below (personDevices) works without any problems. However, when I replace the "123" with a direct access to a value via a foreign key:

```
t3.deviceTypeA.mobile_number
```

... the query returns 0 results. Eventually I'm wanting to do a select statement like the following:

```
number = 
t3.type == "phone" ? t3.deviceTypeA.mobile_number:
t3.type == "computer" ? t3.deviceTypeB.computer_number :
t3.type == "legacy" ? t3.deviceTypeC.legacy_number :
"nodata"
```

Which explains why I need the foreign key, but I've simplified the query for the question.

```
var personDevices = from t1 in db.people
join t2 in db.peopleDevices on t1.person_id equals t2.person_id
join t3 in db.deviceRegistrations on t2.registration_id equals t3.registration_id

select new {
  t1.person_id,
  t1.name,
  t3.type,
  t3.generated_code,
  t3.hardware_id,
  devicetypeA_number = "123"
};
```

For various reasons I've disabled Referential Integrity on the foreign key and removed data checking. Using SQL Server 2008 and running the query under C# .NET 4.

Why does accessing the data in the foreign key table cause the query to return no results, and how do I fix it?

Comment: the snippet that starts "var personDevices" works completely, but when I replace the "123" with "t3.deviceTypeA.mobile_number" it returns no results. I just mentioned that the real thing that I intend to do is to have the snippet starting "number = " replace the line "devicetypeA_number = 123" to make the reason for my need to use a foreign key clear

Comment: I have to wonder if you were actually getting an exception where t3.deviceTypeA was null and swallowing that exception somewhere else in your code. I always recommend turning on break on all exceptions to catch this kind of thing. I see you've worked around the issue already, but thought I'd throw this out there in case anyone else runs into similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could solve this issue. Instead I changed the database structure so that all 3 device types could be referred to in one table via a device_type field and by re-using a column for two different types of reference numbers.

Yes, the design isn't fully normalized, but much much simpler.

I also ended up using inline queries as the results I was tending to get from LINQ did not match my expectations so due to time constraints just gave up and took the easy option instead of messing about.